# Replace video in embedded iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I replace a video embedded in an iframe using JavaScript or jQuery?

My HTML is:

```
  <iframe src="https://openload.co/embed/7Cq9AdeLtL0/" allowfullscreen="true" 
  id="bigframe" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  <a data-link="https://openload.co/embed/5xTolN_ejRI/">openload</a>
```

And the other video source should be in the `<a>` tag so when I click the word "openload", it will change the video source to the second source and another think I need to do this in multiple posts with a variable video

Comment: So in other words, you want to replace a embedded video with another one?

Comment: yes this what i want

Comment: replace the iframe?

Comment: how i can do this with javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any JavaScript.

1. Give the iframe a name ex. `<iframe src='about:blank' name='vid'....`
2. Next, give each link a `target` attribute withe the value of the iframe's name. ex. `<a href='path/to/video.mp4' target='vid'...`

### Demo

Doesn't work here, go to this [**Plunker for a working demo**](http://embed.plnkr.co/iz7rVTGCj2Wos7IqrKwp/)

```html
<a href='http://media6000.dropshots.com/photos/1381926/20170326/005609.mp4' target='vid'>1</a>

<a href='http://media6000.dropshots.com/photos/1381926/20170326/005610.mp4' target='vid'>2</a>

<a href='http://media6000.dropshots.com/photos/1381926/20170326/005611.mp4' target='vid'>3</a>


<iframe src='about:blank' name='vid' width='320' height='180'></iframe>
```

Comment: No problem, happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

It is batter to play video using html video tag instead iframe .You can do it with jquery like below

html

```
<a data-link="https://openload.co/embed/5xTolN_ejRI/" href="#">Video 1</a>  
<a data-link="https://openload.co/embed/5xTolN_ejRI/"  href="#">Video 2</a>  

<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="https://openload.co/embed/5xTolN_ejRI" type="video/mp4">  
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // set video srs 
  $('a').click(function(){
    $("video").html('<source src="'+$(this).data('link')+'"></source>' );
  });   
});
```

Comment: no i want it by the iframe and i have an id for the video for the css

Comment: @chamsagouni Any specific reason you are playing video in iframe instead video tag?

Answer (score 0):

```
const iFrame = document.querySelectorAll("iframe");
// console.log(iFrame)
iFrame.forEach((item, index) => {
  let src = item.src;
  const newItem = document.createElement("video");
  newItem.style = "width:640px; height:360px";
  newItem.src = src;
  item.parentNode.replaceChild(newItem, iFrame[index]);
  newItem.setAttribute("class", "iframe-video-tag-" + index);
  newItem.setAttribute("controls", "true");
  let videoTag = document.getElementsByClassName("iframe-video-tag-" + index);
  videoTag.src = src;
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).